# Present VC modally above other VC - both touchable

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

I want to show a VC above another VC but want both to be clickable and responsible.

I have a textfield which prints out the string behind each @-sign.

When a @ is written I have a VC which pops up with a small tableview above the first VC which should later represent the users who have a name containing the printed out string.

I need the first vc to still be responsible, because currently I can't click buttons and textfields on the first VC when the second one pops up even though I can see everything ( set the background to clear).

```
        if commentTextField.text!.contains("@"){
        print("changed textField")
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "suggestedUsersViewController") as  UIViewController!
        vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        vc?.view.backgroundColor = .clear


        present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

How I get the post behind the @- sign

```
        let caption = commentTextField.text


    let words = caption?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    for var word in words! {
            if word.hasPrefix("@") {
                word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)

                print("wort ist", word)
            }
    }
```

Currently it just pops over the first vc and then its no longer clickable and I cannot change the textfield

Pictures
[image: The first VC (where you write the comment and link users]

[image: The TableView which pops up when a @ is written in the commentTextField]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`present` function will make the second view controller cover the whole page and you will no longer have access from screen to the view controller below the top one.

To accomplish your goal, you need to put a `UITableView` on a view, then keep showing or hiding the view. If you really want another view controller, you can create a containing view and have a embed segue to another `view controller`, like this

[image]